# How to search albums in Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Since FQL is deprecated and won't be available next month already (august/2016), I have to migrate my website to Graph API, but I'm struggling to perform searches in this platform.

In my website I show all albums uploaded to my Facebook Page, this is easy to do with Graph API, but I also have a search field where I can filter the results by title, description or date.

I've been reading the docs and also some questions here on Stack Overflow, but I can't find a way to filter the albums of a page. All I can do is list all albums, I can't find a way to make my search field work.

An alternative could be fetch all albums and filter them locally. But Graph API also limits the results by 50, I can't really fetch everything at once. All I could think of was fetch all, 50 by 50, take as many requests as it needs, then, when all has been fetched, filter them locally. But this is just awlful, there must be another way, I can't belive Facebook is removing FQL completelly without offering an alternative to this.

Comment: There is no other way. Graph API offers very little in terms of filtering or sorting data - and according to FB engineers, that is on purpose, for performance reasons.

Comment: It's sad to know that Facebook isn't offering any new way for us to continue filtering data. Fortunately I don't have too many albums, I'll probably need only two requests with the approach I described.